# Magento controller custom action redirecting

Tags: adminhtml, controllers, ajax

I have a customer action on a customer controller I am creating. My controller extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

Whenever I send a POST request to a customer controller action instead of returning what I set the body to in the action it sends a redirect to the admin dashboard.

I am making this POST request via AJAX and don't want a redirect.

---

Controller:

```
class JB_UPI_Adminhtml_ImportController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    //....

    public function createProductsAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json');

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $storeId        = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);

        $this->getResponse()->setBody('{"_success":true}');
    }

    //....
}
```

JavaScript making AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: createEndpoint,
    type: 'POST',
    data: outputData
})
.success(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

**SOLVED**

I found this [article](http://dltr.org/blog/magento/457/Magento-admin-redirects-to-dashboard-when-submitting-form-solved) which mentioned a `form_key`. Adding that to my AJAX POST request solved the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some code, it is impossible to see what's going on.

Comment: @sr_magento I've added some code

Comment: where does it redirect to?

Comment: @Sander-MageStackDay2015 I've edited the question. It redirects me to the admin dashboard

Comment: Just in case the solved link ever 404's, the solution provided is to add the following to the form: `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />`

Comment: It's unfortunate that this was closed - the question is valid and there's a valid solution.